# Media Session connector #onCommand not getting called

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, mediacontroller, android-mediasession, mediabrowserservicecompat

I am building a simple media app following the android official [app](https://github.com/android/uamp). But in my case, I need to fetch URL of each clip from remote and then create a `mediaId` out of it and then play an audio clip. This means that I need to update my media data very frequently. For updating the media data list I am registering the custom command receiver, and it works fine it updates data and play as required. But after a calling `sendCommand` specific number of times (7-8) `onCommand` not getting called.
You can check my implementation.

Call from ViewModel

```
private fun sendCommandToService(metaData: List<ServiceMetaData>) {
        audioConnection.sendCommand(AudioService.REFRESH_AUDIO_DATA, Bundle().apply {
            putSerializable(AudioService.AUDIO_DATA, metaData as ArrayList<ServiceMetaData>)
        }) { _, _ -> }
    }
```

Service connection

```
fun sendCommand(
        command: String,
        parameters: Bundle?,
        resultCallback: ((Int, Bundle?) -> Unit)
    ) = if (mediaBrowser.isConnected) {
        mediaController.sendCommand(command, parameters, object : ResultReceiver(Handler()) {
            override fun onReceiveResult(resultCode: Int, resultData: Bundle?) {
                resultCallback(resultCode, resultData)
            }
        })
        true
    } else {
        false
    }
```

Media Session connector custom command receiver

```
override fun onCommand(
        player: Player?,
        controlDispatcher: ControlDispatcher?,
        command: String?,
        extras: Bundle?,
        callback: ResultReceiver?
    ): Boolean =
        when (command) {
            REFRESH_AUDIO_DATA -> onRefreshAudioListCommandCallback(extras ?: Bundle.EMPTY, callback)
            else -> false
        }
```

This behavior is intermittent, on the emulator I faced this after repeating the same procedure 7-8 times but on a real device, this happens after 18-20 calls.

Comment: Did you get any solution or alternative for this question ?. If yes, please post it here.